# Problem in creating new table ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my instruction :
it works on my friend computer !

```
CREATE TABLE  typeRdv1(
    id_type int  PRIMARY KEY,
    des VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE  rdv1(
    id_rdv int  PRIMARY KEY,
    cin_pat VARCHAR(20),
    date_rdv VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    type_rdv VARCHAR(20),
    state VARCHAR(20),

    CONSTRAINT `FK_cin_rdv` FOREIGN KEY (cin_pat)
    REFERENCES patients(cin_pat) ON DELETE NO ACTION,

    CONSTRAINT `FK_id_type_rdv` FOREIGN KEY (type_rdv) 
    REFERENCES typeRdv1(id_type) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

> A ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Any help !

Comment: see the line: date_rdv VARCHAR NOT NULL, you need to give length to your varchar variable. try: date_rdv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

Comment: @ErayBalkanli now it's Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"

Comment: Doesn't it say on which line?

Comment: You also need to get rid of the back-tics on your constraint names-- those are only used in MySQL (and MariaDB and SQLite (in compatibility mode)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure all the "varchar" fields has a length defined. In your second table, it says: `date_rdv VARCHAR NOT NULL`, which I believe causing the issue, so try to change it into `date_rdv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL` and try again.

```
...
CREATE TABLE  rdv1(
    id_rdv int  PRIMARY KEY,
    cin_pat VARCHAR(20),
    date_rdv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, --length added to varchar 
    type_rdv VARCHAR(20),
    state VARCHAR(20),
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

The reason you get "invalid character" error is that you cannot use "on delete no action" while creating a table with a constraint. Instead you should alter your table after to create your constraints with "on delete cascade" option. Probably like below ( you may need to drop your constraints first):

```
CREATE TABLE  patients(
    cin_pat int  PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE  typeRdv1(
    id_type int  PRIMARY KEY,
    des VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE rdv1(
    id_rdv int  PRIMARY KEY,
    cin_pat VARCHAR(20),
    date_rdv VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type_rdv VARCHAR(20),
    state VARCHAR(20)
);

alter table rdv1 add (
    CONSTRAINT FK_cin_rdv FOREIGN KEY (cin_pat)
    REFERENCES patients (cin_pat) ON DELETE cascade,

    CONSTRAINT FK_id_type_rdv FOREIGN KEY (type_rdv) 
    REFERENCES typeRdv1 (id_type) ON DELETE cascade
);
```

Check this for more details: https://www.haidongji.com/2006/07/24/defining-no-action-foreign-key-constraints-in-oracle/comment-page-1/

Comment: thansk for your help but after trying this it show me this error
Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"

Comment: Also Oracle uses `VARCHAR2` not `VARCHAR`. (`VARCHAR` exists but the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#SQLRF-GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E) has a clear warning not to use it.)

Comment: The problem is not that the length wasn't specified on varchar column, although that is the error! The problem is the column shouldn't be character of any format; it should be DATE. Either that or change the name from date_rdv to something else. It's just that column name containing 'date' does not fit well with character type; at least IMHO.